# $.click not firing on checkbox, in Chrome with JQuery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

The click event does not seem to be firing on the checkbox in this block of in-memory html. It does fire for the button but not the checkbox.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X2en3/18/

And the code:

Fired with .trigger(): 
   Fired with .click():

```
var working = $('<div><input type="checkbox" id="myBox"/><button id="myButton"/><div>'),    
checkbox = working.find('#myBox'),
button = working.find('#myButton'),
stage;

function boxclicked() {$('#' + stage).append('--checkbox');}
function buttonclicked() {$('#' + stage).append('--button');}

working.delegate('#myBox', {click: boxclicked});
working.delegate('#myButton', {click: buttonclicked});

stage = 'trigger';

checkbox.trigger('click');
button.trigger('click');

stage = 'click';

checkbox.click();
button.click();
```

This is only happening with Chrome and JQuery 1.9.1. Firefox/IE 9 and previous versions of JQuery all work fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Additional testing: appending to body makes it work, and using direct binding rather than event delegation also works (with it not bound to body.) This suggests that click events on checkboxes that are not part of the DOM do not bubble in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

From jquery.com

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.
>   For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to
>   use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation
>   is in the .on() method. In general, these are the equivalent templates
>   for the two methods:

Try using the `on` method

http://api.jquery.com/on/

---

```
var $checkbox = $("<input>", { type: "checkbox", id: "myBox" });
var $button = $("<button>", { type: "checkbox", id: "myButton" });

var $container = $("<div>");
$container.append($checkbox);
$container.append($button);

$("body").append($container);

$container.on("click", "#myBox", getCheckboxStatus);
$container.on("click", "#myButton", getButtonStatus);

function getCheckboxStatus() {
    $('#chckBoxVerify').append('Yes');
}

function getButtonStatus() {
    $('#buttonVerify').append('Yes');
}

$checkbox.click();
$button.click();
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/X2en3/22/

Comment: Your code example is significantly different from the one I provided. Your sample has the button/checkbox appended to the body, mine doesn't. This seems to make a difference.

Comment: Changing yours to not append to the body, and the checkbox click doesn't fire, http://jsfiddle.net/X2en3/23/  . It does fire in JQuery 1.8.3